# Tag synonym for serpentine and serpentine-belt?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

While asking my first ever question on this site ([What advances in material technology, have made serpentine belts last longer?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/83371/44515)), I noticed that [serpentine-belt](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serpentine-belt) had about 35 questions, and [serpentine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serpentine) had only 5. I therefore used [serpentine-belt](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serpentine-belt)  instead of [serpentine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serpentine).

Then I looked at the [serpentine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serpentine) tag (which didn't even have usage guidance) and 100% of the questions were on-topic at [serpentine-belt](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serpentine-belt), so I suggested 5 edits (switching serpentine to the more popular and more descriptive tag), and now I suggest making these two tag synonyms, so that this doesn't happen again. ***Does anyone disagree?***

Mods: please forgive me for mentioning this also in a flag. It turns out I can't post on Meta for 40 minutes after posting on Main, due to my very low rep.

Comment: I don't disagree and appreciate the catch ... since you are a regular on SE, I'm thinking it's all good and you know how things roll. I'll see about getting it cleaned up! Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned up all the tags. I'll create a tag synonym to ensure it doesn't happen anymore.

Note: Done